Best way to calculate velocity, acceleration and jerk with different temporal resolutions
I have body motion tracking data I am using for my thesis. I am trying to find relationships between the kinematics of the body of speakers, and the acoustic measures of their speech (e.g. speech envelope, pitch, intensity...).
Before performing analyses such as coherence or mutual information, I downsample my data from 200 Hz to 50 Hz (mostly to speed up computation time).
On the following graphs, you'll see the original data (sampled at 200 Hz) in blue, and the linearly-resampled data in orange (at 50 Hz).
Here is the x, y, and z position across time for one of my markers (the right hand of one speaker). The two curves are on top of each other:

So far so good. Then, I plot the distance traveled, i.e. the Euclidian distance between a point a times $t_1$ and $t_2$:
$$d_{t_{2}} = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}$$
Because my temporal resolution is not the same, then I get the following graph. The orange curve is roughly four times more ample than the blue, which is logical as the temporal resolution is 4 times lower:

Now, to standardize this, I use velocities: because I divide the distance traveled between two timestamps by the time elapsed, the curves overlay again. We can see, thanks to this, that the downsampling removed some fast movements - which is fine because the motion capture comes with some jitter:
$$v_{t_{2}} = \frac{d_{t_{2}}}{t_2-t_1}$$

Now, this is fine to study the variations of velocity with the acoustic measures mentioned earlier. However, the literature mentions some relationships with the acceleration phases of movement - I am then also interested in studying the acceleration, and the jerk to see the variations in acceleration.
I use this formula to calculate the acceleration:
$$a_{t_{3}} = \operatorname{abs}\left(\frac{v_{t_{3}} - v_{t_{2}}}{t_3-t_2}\right)$$
The problem is that, this time, due to my differences in temporal resolution, I get differences in acceleration amplitudes:

This might be a problem for the future analyses - especially if I need to analyses the jerk, which should reduce the amplitudes by a factor 16 compared to the original 200 Hz data.
My question is the following: How can I preserve the relative amplitude despite the downsampling?
Thanks for your answers :)

Why are you taking the absolute value in calculating the acceleration?

Because I am interested in the changes in acceleration, so i figured it would be an easier way to correlate the absolute value to, say, the envelope of the speech. Do you think I am mistaken?

If you don't get an answer here, you may want to try [dsp.se] with regards to the analysis (though you may need to change some of the focus?)

PRO TIP: Is not the same to take the norm of the distance and differentiating then, than differentiating first and then taking the norm of the acceleration. Your first euclidean norm formula is nonsense as an approach to solve your problem. If you plot the positions nondownsampled and downsampled, how different they are? I guess you blundered your script rather than being in need of more sophisticated techniques of signal processing.
